# creating 3 threads and each doing individual work using semapore for synchronization. how can i do it?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

The question says that Thread1 takes input of 2 numbers. Thread2 asks for choice (Add/Sub). Thread3 performs calculation and main thread prints result. Use semaphore for synchronization.
How can I divide the threads and each will perform different things. I'm new in this so I'm pretty confused.

Comment: For synchronization between threads, you may want to use mutexes instead. See the `mtx_` functions @ [Thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, A pthread.h mutex can't be unlocked by a different thread than the one that locked it. Is it the same for thread.h mutexes? If so, you'd need a cond var too. But this is some kind of assignment that requires semaphores, so best to use that. Semaphores would work quite well here anyway.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I guess one could spin a _lock-check_if_its_my_time_to_run-unlock_ cycle but that would eat CPU so using a condition variable is preferable. Raisa: The functions for the standard condition variables are on the same page, named `cnd_`

Comment: @TedLyngmo ??  There is no need for any lock-checking if semaphores are used.

Comment: @MartinJames No, that was a reply to ikegami w.r.t. the need to add a condition variable if a mutex is used. It had nothing to do with semaphores.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ah... OK, sorry:)

Comment: @MartinJames No worries :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Our needs**

- Thread 2 needs to wait until thread 1 tells it data is available.
- Thread 3 needs to wait until thread 2 tells it data is available.

**Our tools**

Semaphores have two operations:

- *post*: Increment the value of the semaphore.
- *wait*: Wait until the value of the semaphore is positive and decrement its value.

We also get to initialize it to a value of our choice.

**Thread 2 needs to wait for thread 1 to tell it data is available**

Thread 2 will need to use a *wait*, since that's the only operation that waits. And it only waits if the semaphore is non-positive (zero or negative), so the semaphore will have to be initialized to a non-positive value.

**Thread 1 needs to tell thread 2 data is available**

Since thread 2 is waiting for a semaphore to become positive, we can initialize the semaphore to 0, and thread 1 can use a *post* operation to make it positive when it's time to wake up thread 2.

**Communication between thread 2 and thread 3**

This is identical to the communication between thread 1 and thread 2. So we'll use a second semaphore in an identical manner.